# How do I filter with date In VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

I have the following code, and I want the user to just set a date like "22/06/2015" 
and have that date go to a filter. The problem is that when I go to filter I have at first year,
 then I check a year, appears the months then the days. (I'm just showing a part of the code)

```
Sub PassaProRelatorio(planilha As Worksheet, nome As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Dim contaLinha As Integer
Dim array1 As Variant
Dim mes As String
mes = InputBox("Digite até a data que deseja EX: 27/02/2015")
array1 = Array(1, mes)
Sheets("BasePenhoras").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$DO$80000").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=nome
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$DO$80000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
    "Concluído"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$DO$80000").AutoFilter Field:=72, Criteria1:= _
    "Bloqueio"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$DO$80000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=array1here
```

Comment: Can you just clarify your question? It's not very clear what you exactly want after reading it.

Comment: Yeah I know it's hard to explain. I want to filter a sheet per date. But first I have to filter the year them the month and last the day. How do I do that. But with the input box get the parameter to filter, for example a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change your date to the format you are looking for if i understand your problem correctly:

```
Format(DateValue(mes), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Comment: My problem is filter dates in VBA, because it keep open checkBoxes and I don't know how to ckeck them with VBA